# different Unit Test behaviour between MatLab 2015A and 2015B

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

Consider the following unit test method in a unit test class named CEmpty < matlab.unittest.TestCase:

```
function test_must_fail (testCase)
    testCase.verifyLessThan(2,1, 'test_must_fail() failed') ;
end
```

expected result:

```
...
    Actual double:
             2
    Maximum Value (Exclusive):
             1
...
```

in MatLab R2015A, i can get this result in both ways:

```
% first way:
tester = TEmpty() ;
tester.test_must_fail() ;

% second way
run (TEmpty, 'test_must_fail') ;
```

whoever, in R2015B, only the second way results in output, while the first does not display anything.  moreover, trying to save the result to a variable:

```
tester = TEmpty() ;
test_result = tester.test_must_fail() ;
```

works fine in 2015A, but result in an error ("*Too many output arguments*."
) in R2015B.

before I start to change my code:
1. do you get similar results, or is it only my (and my colleagues) installation?
2. if this is the expected behavior, is there some easy bypass (such as setting some configuration to 2015A mode)?

Answer (score 3):

This is an expected behavior and was done as a result of confusion with respect to people using classes that were purely for interactive use showing output that looked like a failure but actually doesn't produce a failure on a returned TestResult.

Here's the relevant [release note](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#buzej11-27).

You can now do this in a safer fashion, ensuring that it is only done for interactive debugging use cases, by using the new form of TestCase.forInteractiveuse. Try:

```
tester = matlab.unittest.TestCase.forInteractiveUse(?TEmpty);
tester.test_must_fail();
```